# jScrollPane doesn't sitck to bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, jscrollpane

I use jScrollPane for the scrollbars in a simple chat interface I designed. The issue I have here is that jScrollPane doesn't scroll to the bottom automatically. jScrollPane does have a handy option 'stickToBottom' that I've set to true and also I've set 'autoReinitalise' to true since content gets added to the specific div dynamically. Now, as soon as the chatbox is getting filled and scrollbars are added I expected jScrollPane to automatically scroll to the bottom and stick there. But this isn't the case. I first manually have to scroll to the bottom and then it will stick there. So I tried to create an innerdiv with the height 1 pixel more than it's parent (that has the scrollbars) so that from the beginning scrollbars are visible. Via the api I then scroll to 100% over the Y-axis so that the scrollhandle is totally down. But also in this case when my chatbox is being filled and content is exceeding the available space the scrollbar doesn't stick to the bottom, it even scrolls almost to the top again.

I've set up a very simple testpage that has this issue:

http://www.webtrail.nl/jscrollpane-example

Hope someone can help me out here. Thanks!

Comment: Can you paste your html + css + js into a jsfiddle?

Comment: I've updated my post with a link to an example page.

Comment: Did you try the maintainPosition option?

Comment: Yes, I've set maintainPosition to true.

Answer (score 1):

You should have `maintainPosition` and `stickToBottom` enabled by default, but the tricky part is calling `scrollToBottom()` only once, when the content will fully occupy the scroll div's height, and you should be doing because you still want the `maintainPosition` feature to work (so that if the user scrolls to the top, he stays there even if new content arrives).

If you call `scrollToBottom()` multiple times, it will scroll to the bottom each time (thus eliminating the `maintainPosition` feature).

If the initial content is bigger than the height of the page then you can call `scrollToBottom` on page load, but if not you need to calculate when the content size = scroll div height.

I made an approach to exemplify this (when I add 24 divs the div needs scrolling so I call `scrollToBottom` then):

```
var counter = 1;
function addDummyContentToChatBox(api) {
    $("<div>This is some dummy content.</div>").appendTo("#chatbox_inner");
    if (counter == 24) {
        api.scrollToBottom(false);
    }
    api.reinitialise();
    counter++;
}

$(function() {

    var api = $('#chatbox').jScrollPane({
      stickToBottom: true,
      maintainPosition: true
    }).data('jsp');

    setInterval(function() {
      addDummyContentToChatBox(api);
    }, 233);
});
```

Full source: http://jsfiddle.net/STHgr/37/

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I don't think this is the real solution though. Why did you call scrollToBottom after 24 times and not after 21 times, when the chatarea is actually full? I tried to edit your jsfiddle and set it to 21 but then it doesn't work correctly. Also, I did call ScrollToBottom only once in my example, right after creating the jScrollPane. This should work since the innercontent is 1px heigher than the chatbox. It didn't work though. But after making the innercontent 50px heigher than the chatbox it did work! So it seems like some miscalculation in the jScrollPane plugin.

Comment: As I said the number may vary and may not be the perfect solution, but the idea is important (!). When the chatbox is higher than the height of the div, only then should you call scrollToBottom (not before!), that's the whole trick. And you should call it just once. It worked for me.

Comment: I understand. But my point is that it's not just a question of calling scrollToBottom when the chatbox is heigher than the div, aparently it has to be a lot heigher than the div. And this is wrong. In the example that you posted on jsfiddle there are 20 lines available in the chatbox. So calling scrollToBottom the 21th iteration should do the trick. But that doesn't work, neither the 22th does. So calling scrollToBottom only once, true, I agree. But it doesn't work as supposed when called at the right moment.

Comment: The example is a good one. I modified it slightly here: http://jsfiddle.net/STHgr/39/ - this would be the recommended way of getting it to work. Unfortunately there does appear to be a bug in jScrollPane and the isCloseToBottom function. I'll have to look through the plugin history to see why that function is there and if it can be fixed... In the meantime you can keep calling scrollToBottom() until there has been any user mouse interaction with the contents of the jScrollPane